# What are the drug testing procedures for EU airlines?

Tags: airline-operations, easa-regulations, medical

How do EU airlines test aircrew for drug use, specifically marijuana? Do they use hair tests, and how far back in time can they detect marijuana use?

Comment: Maybe you can simplify your question, which boils down to "Are drug tests used by the EU airlines  able to detect I smoked one cigarette of marijuana 3 months ago".

Comment: @mins Well, there's "are they able to?" and there's the implicit "is it necessarily going to be a problem?". (I don't know the extent to which the latter is relevant; it may well be *very* relevant, or the OP might be able to show that this really was a one-off incident and it might not be a showstopper.)

Comment: @michael-kjörling I would say I drink less than an average person, maybe drinking more than one beer only once every three weeks, it was  a special occasion.

Comment: what im looking for here is someone who has any experience with getting hired in the EU, and who could let me know what kind of testing is regularly used, as I have no contacts in the industry....

Comment: *"I have never been a drug user in my life, I smoked marijuana"* - You don't show any awareness of the contradiction here. Particularly [in context](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cannabis_in_the_United_Kingdom#Legality)

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick I am aware of it, what I meant by drug user is someone who uses drugs with any regularity, which is of course not my case. I am aware of the illegality of the subject, I was not in personal possession of any of it, and never have been.

Answer (score 2):

I am not a pilot but you may find the following useful:

[Civil Aviation Authority, INFORMATION NOTICE, Number: IN–2015/012](https://publicapps.caa.co.uk/docs/33/InformationNotice2015012.pdf)

> 5 Drug and Alcohol Screening Programme
> 5.1 The  testing  process.
> Trained  staff  should  carry  out  screening  tests  usually  by  mouth  swab,  breath,  blood,  hair   or  urine  sample.  Tests  are  becoming  simpler  to  administer  and  less  invasive  as  the  technology  continues  to  improve.  Minimal  notice  should  be  given  of  the  intention  to  undertake  random  testing.  The  sample  collection  and  testing  process  should  be  designed  to  ensure  the  result  is  reliable.  If  a  positive  result  is  found  further  (usually  blood)  testing should be undertaken. A confirmed positive result should be reported to the relevant Civil Aviation Authority regulatory authority; in the UK the report should be sent to the Medical Department of  UK CAA  for aviation licence holders.

It is easy to find companies whose business is testing UK pilots for drugs, for example [AlphaBioLabs](https://www.alphabiolabs.co.uk/workplace-testing-sectors/aviation-industry-drug-alcohol-testing/):

> #### Protecting the aviation industry with drug and alcohol testing
>
> We specialise in providing drug and alcohol testing to the aviation industry for both individuals who want to show that they are drug or alcohol-free and companies as part of their drug and alcohol testing policy.
>
> Our aviation industry workplace testing consists of the following:
>
> - Random drug and alcohol testing
> - Pre-employment drug and alcohol screening
> - For-cause drug and alcohol screening
> - Post-incident drug and alcohol testing
> - Abstinence monitoring
>
> We have a team of fully trained sample collectors in your area, ready to collect your drug and/or alcohol samples from your place of work or any safe environment.

...

> Hair drug testing
>
> Hair drug testing is a form of workplace drug testing that can be used to support other methods such as oral fluid and urine testing.
>
> It can be particularly useful for a more comprehensive overview of a person’s drug use as it is known as a ‘wide-window’ form of testing, which can determine a history of drug intake for up to 12 months.

A different lab [reports](https://blog.cansfordlabs.co.uk/the-drug-and-alcohol-testing-blog/drug-testing-for-pilots-the-rules-around-the-world)

> British Airways, for example, tests urine for drugs and breath for alcohol. Workers can be randomly tested in the first six months of employment or if returning to work after rehabilitation, and can also be tested if it is suspected that drugs or alcohol may have caused an accident, or if they are suspected of being under the influence while working.

Relevant incidents might include things like [this](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/destinations/asia/kazakhstan/articles/pilot-caught-with-weed-after-flight-sacked/):

> Air Astana, which is part-owned by UK firm BAE Systems, said it fired the pilot immediately and had a zero tolerance policy for drugs and alcohol.
>
> In a statement to Reuters it said: “The airline regularly tests its crews for alcohol and drugs using a random sampling method."

Answer (score -2):

I'm not a pilot, but I'm a drug testing lab engineer and can provide some info. There is the EU airline drug testing for aircrews is conducted in accordance with the EASA’s regulations.

On 24 March 2015, a tragic accident sparked the adoption of Commission Regulation (EU) 2018/1042 by the European Commission. This regulation requires alcohol and other psychoactive substances testing for flight crew and cabin crew members on aircraft using aerodromes in Member States - an obligation that has been applicable since 14 February 2021.

Pre-employment, random, reasonable suspicion, and post-accident tests are all required by the EASA to ensure safety while flying. The most common form of drug test used is urine testing. However, hair tests can be performed too but only on occasion. Hair testing can detect marijuana use up to 90 days after consumption, that is why it is used only if it is needed to check a pilot for long-term drug consumption. There is provided [pilot drug testing at Claritas Genomics](https://claritasgenomics.com/do-pilots-drugtested), if you want to know what you might be up to, the up-to-date article can come in handy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: the name of the company does not sounds related to drug testing, and the company allegedly closed down 5 years ago (https://www.insideprecisionmedicine.com/news-and-features/claritas-genomics-ceases-operations-five-years-after-spinout/) I don't see how this answer is relevant